# Getting console.log output from Chrome with Selenium Python API bindings

Tags: python, google-chrome, logging, selenium

I'm using Selenium to run tests in Chrome via the Python API bindings, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to configure Chrome to make the `console.log` output from the loaded test available.  I see that there are `get_log()` and `log_types()` methods on the WebDriver object, and I've seen [Get chrome's console log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261338/get-chromes-console-log/18283831#18283831) which shows how to do things in Java.  But I don't see an equivalent of Java's `LoggingPreferences` type in the Python API.  Is there some way to accomplish what I need?

Comment: The answers here no longer work for Selenium 4. The current answer is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66465158/get-info-and-warnings-consol-logs-from-chrome-with-selenium-from-specific-comman

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Ok, finally figured it out:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

# enable browser logging
d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
d['loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=d)

# load the desired webpage
driver.get('http://foo.com')

# print messages
for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
    print(entry)
```

Entries whose `source` field equals `'console-api'` correspond to console messages, and the message itself is stored in the `message` field.

Starting from chromedriver, 75.0.3770.8, you have to use goog:loggingPrefs instead of loggingPrefs:

```
d['goog:loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }
```

Comment: Hm. Investigating how to do this with chrome_options after trying this out and getting: `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py:54: DeprecationWarning: Desired Capabilities has been deprecated, please user chrome_options.
  warnings.warn("Desired Capabilities has been deprecated, please user chrome_options.", DeprecationWarning)`

Comment: I use `webdriver.Remote` with a capability of `browserName="chrome"` to instantiate my driver, and it keeps telling me `AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'get_log'`.  When I go to the source, I'm struggling to find the `get_log` implementation used in this lovely answer.  I suspect I've gone horribly astray... somewhere. Wish I knew where! http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/search.html?q=get_log&check_keywords=yes&area=default

Comment: @kiminoa I had this issue with selenium `2.33.0`, upgrade to `2.45.0` fixed it.

Comment: Is there something similar for IE ? I already checked https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities. Looks like there isn't

Comment: @binithb no idea; you probably want to ask a separate top-level question

Comment: Looks like I can comment out `d['loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }` and get same results. Also, any way for console logs to not just be `'level':'SEVERE'` ?

Comment: @Shane you need to wait a few seconds with `time.sleep(5)` or your browser will quit without console.log executed. This is my case.

Comment: you just saved my remaining sanity, thanks man.

Answer (score 18):

To complete the answer: starting from chromedriver 75.0.3770.8, you have to use `goog:loggingPrefs` instead of `loggingPrefs`.

See Chromedriver changelog: http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads or this bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2976

Comment: Thanks! Want to edit the main answer with an additional sentence including this clarification?

Answer (score 4):

if you are using the python logging module (and you should be)... here is a way to add the selenium browser logs to the python logging system..

the `get_browser_log_entries()` function grabs the logs from eth provded driver, emits them to the python logging module as chrome. (ie chrome.console-api, chrome.network etc..) using the timestamp from the browser.(in case there is a delay before you call get_log)

it could probably do with some better exception handling (like if logging is not turned on ) etc.. but it works most of the time..

hop

```
import logging

from selenium import webdriver

def get_browser_log_entries(driver):
    """get log entreies from selenium and add to python logger before returning"""
    loglevels = { 'NOTSET':0 , 'DEBUG':10 ,'INFO': 20 , 'WARNING':30, 'ERROR':40, 'SEVERE':40, 'CRITICAL':50}

    #initialise a logger
    browserlog = logging.getLogger("chrome")
    #get browser logs
    slurped_logs = driver.get_log('browser')
    for entry in slurped_logs:
        #convert broswer log to python log format
        rec = browserlog.makeRecord("%s.%s"%(browserlog.name,entry['source']),loglevels.get(entry['level']),'.',0,entry['message'],None,None)
        rec.created = entry['timestamp'] /1000 # log using original timestamp.. us -> ms
        try:
            #add browser log to python log
            browserlog.handle(rec)
        except:
            print(entry)
    #and return logs incase you want them
    return slurped_logs

def demo():
    caps = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
    caps['goog:loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps )

    driver.get("http://localhost")

    consolemsgs = get_browser_log_entries(driver)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)7s:%(message)s')
    logging.info("start")
    demo()
    logging.info("end")
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that calling `driver.get_log('browser')` will cause the next call to return nothing until more logs are written to the console.

I would suggest saving the logs to a variable first. For example below `logs_2` will equal `[]`.

If you need something in the console to test you can use:

```
self.driver.execute_script("""

                function myFunction() {
                      console.log("Window loaded")
                }

                if(window.attachEvent) {
            window.attachEvent('onload', myFunction());
        } else {
            if(window.onload) {
                var curronload = window.onload;
                var newonload = function(evt) {
                    curronload(evt);
                    myFunction(evt);
                };
                window.onload = newonload;
            } else {
                window.onload = myFunction();
            }
        }
                """)
```

---

```
logs_1 = driver.get_log('browser')
print("A::", logs_1 )
logs_2 = driver.get_log('browser')
print("B::", logs_2 )
for entry in logs_1:
    print("Aa::",entry)

for entry in logs_2:
    print("Bb::",entry)
```

See the answer from msridhar for what should go above my example code.