# Capture JSON response through Selenium

Tags: selenium

I'm testing a webpage using Selenium (either IDE or webdriver). The webpage has a "search" function, basically just a GET call with params. The javascript also output to console the JSON returned from the search call, i.e. something like `console.log(data)`. And I'm able to inspect the response data in Firefox console.

My question is: is there anyway I can capture this `data` from Firefox console in Selenium (so that I can further inspect and doing asserts)? Writing a direct GET request (eg, from Python) does not work since the search url is protected through a login page.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting console.log output from Chrome with Selenium Python API bindings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907180/getting-console-log-output-from-chrome-with-selenium-python-api-bindings)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Selenium doesnt provide any in built API/method to play with console.
You can redirect console output file and read from file.
Link: [**How to redirect Firefox console output to file.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.dump)

Answer (score 0):

It was possible at one point using Firebug. Not sure if it still works.