# Detect javascript console output with python

Tags: javascript, python

When I'm working in a javascript-heavy application I like to use Console.log() a lot for debugging. However, I want to ensure I've properly suppressed all console logging in production.

I'd like to create a python script to walk through a site and generate a list of pages that write something to the console. I know I could just have it rip through the javascript files before minimization and search for "Console.Log" but I'm often the analyst on a project and consequently don't have access to the codebase. We also have a ton of sites that haven't been touched in a while but could use a scan (great intern project :-) ).

Is this doable with python?

Comment: You can use `urllib` to read the source looking for logs.

Comment: A sufficiently determined opponent could forever keep their console logging functionality from being detected. Ex. with `eval(rot13(pbafbyr.ybt("Uryyb")))`, just doing a search for "console" won't find it. The only way to be 100% sure that your program doesn't log, is to run all possible code paths with all possible inputs... But of course, most programs are not written by your arch-enemy, so just looking for "console.log" ought to catch 99% of cases.

Comment: doing something like `console.log = console.warn = console.dir = console.debug = console.time = console.timeEnd = console.assert = function () {};` etc would supress all console logging

Comment: Thanks @MalikBrahimi. I understand how I could find particular text or element in the page source with urllib but I don't understand how I would find console output? If the javascript has been minimized I can't just look for ".log()".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you can do is to use [`selenium` browser automation tool](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) and check the console logs:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities    

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capabilities['loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)

driver.get('http://foo.com')

# print console log messages
for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
    print entry
```

Taken from [Getting console.log output from Chrome with Selenium Python API bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907180/getting-console-log-output-from-chrome-with-selenium-python-api-bindings).

Comment: Thanks @alecxe. This could be a good solution though I'd rather not be dependent on having chrome installed on the machine, which I assume would be the case

Comment: @user1159067 nope, you can also use `Firefox`, `Safari`, IE or a headless `PhantomJS` browser.

Comment: Side note: to close window after you have printed the output, use driver.close()