# How can I read console log (e.g. messages like ok, connected..) of particular website by using a python coding?

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, api, selenium

I would like to know how to read console log output for a particular website using Python for the automation.

Currently i am trying to read console data using Selenium, but there is no function that I can use to read my logs, I can read the messages but I cannot read the real time data.

Is there any other library that can I use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect javascript console output with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678872/detect-javascript-console-output-with-python)

Comment: I have tried this command as well but it will not giving me a exact input , that will only displaying warning messages.

Answer (score 2):

One way, how to do it, is to launch Chrome with: `chrome.exe" --enable-logging`.

Then you can write a function, which would read chrome_debug.log in real time, for example something like this:

```
   source = open(r'C:\Users\spolm\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\chrome_debug.log' , encoding="utf-8")`
   export=[]
   for line in source:  
     try:
        loadline=line.strip()
        x+=1
        export.append(loadline)

      except UnicodeEncodeError:
        line.strip()
        x+=1
        pass
      except UnicodeDecodeError:
        line.strip()
        x+=1
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

So turns out it's not that trivial. Didn't have the time to try it, but  may have found some options:

**Option A**

1. [Get console content with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846078/how-to-read-from-chromes-console-in-javascript)
2. [Run JS with webdriver: `driver.execute_script(script,*args)`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script)
3. [Get value back to python from selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40735442/how-to-return-value-from-javascript-using-selenium)

**Option B**

Chrome devtools API with Selenium:

[Selenium side](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_cdp_cmd)

[DevTools side](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Log)