# How to read print statement from dart in Chrome using Selenium with Python?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, dart

I have a basic event handler I am testing receives a callback, written in Dart:

```
void handleMouseOverEvent(MouseEvent e){
  print(' x:'+ e.client.x.toString() + ' y:' + e.client.y.toString());
}
```

I am using Selenium to automate a test verifying this method is called. My plan is to write the XY coordinates of the event to verify it is called.

I am using a python selenium script to do this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

from MouseMoves import TestMouseMoves

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capabilities['loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get("http://localhost:63343/Dart_WebStorm/web/index.html")


TestMouseMoves()

for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
    print entry

for entry in driver.get_log('driver'):
    print entry

driver.close()
```

Based on [Getting console.log output from Chrome with Selenium Python API bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907180) (though using Dart and not Javascript for log generation).

TestMouseMoves is a method to fake mouse movement by moving my mouse cursor all over the screen.

I have verified that my Dart application is printing console output in the selenium instance. By removing the driver.close() and investigating the console log for the created session, I see the below.

[image]

I do not know why I am not seeing these logs in my two print statements. Those are the only two logs available (driver.log_types returns `[u'browser', u'driver']`). [Selenium documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html) suggests there are also client/server logs available (but these do not seem to be captured here).

My python selenium script prints out the below message, which suggests the *first* entry in the console is being printed (it appears to match the first entry):

> {u'source': u'deprecation', u'message': u'deprecation 0:0 /deep/ combinator is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120 for more details.', u'timestamp': 1448212138717, u'level': u'WARNING'}

I have also tried `window.console.log('stuff here');` instead of print for the Dart logging as well. And I have added a 4 second delay before my print to help with potential timing issues.

How can I modify either my Dart and/or Python selenium script to retrieve and print the logs generated by this mouseover event?

Comment: Ok, at least I now understand your question ;-). The first message is generated by Chrome itself. The others are log statements from Dart `print()` statments, the former are provided by selenium, the later are missing.

Comment: You could try to call `window.console.log()` methods directly from Dart instead of `print()` [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/1f7565df6d1b9c6ad8ce)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am wondering if it also relates to Selenium only seeing browser/driver logs (and not client/server) in this case? I am not experienced enough with Selenium to try to force them to generate those logs, however...

Comment: I also don't have much experience with Selenium yet.