# What is the easiest way to get chrome browser console logs with Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

What is the easiest way to get chrome console js errors with Selenium python

This is what i am using but I am not able to get full error message

```
results = (self.driver.get_log('browser'))
print results
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is working:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

dc = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
dc['goog:loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=dc)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
    print(entry)
 
driver.quit()
```

Comment: didn't help.. It's exited without showing any log. The exact code I've tried

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907180/getting-console-log-output-from-chrome-with-selenium-python-api-bindings) will help? Looks like you need to pass on the desired capabilities before getting the log.

Comment: i tried that but it does not give the full error message.

Comment: Oh, that's too bad. :(