# How can I open the inspect element tab of any browser in Selenium with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I open the inspect element tab of any browser in Selenium with Python?
I need it after login to page e.g FaceBook, to open the inspect element so I can later take screenshots of console errors. like in this image:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting console.log output from Chrome with Selenium Python API bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907180/getting-console-log-output-from-chrome-with-selenium-python-api-bindings)