# Selenium Log with DesiredCapabilities - only with status error

Tags: python, selenium

I have a problem, I need create a log from my test (Selenium, python). I know how to write all logs,

That is too much. I would like only logs with errors. In addition, I noticed that I do not have a "POST" log in. How to correct the code?

```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities        
        caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
        caps['loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps)
        self.driver.get('http://site/login')
        for entry in self.driver.get_log('performance'):
            print(entry['message'])
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the log level:

**EDIT:**

Just change this line: `caps['loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}`

To:

```
caps['loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'WARNING'}
```

---

If you are using local log you can try setting the level with options:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('log-level=1')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\path\to\chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
```

This is the levels:

- INFO = 0,
- WARNING = 1,
- LOG_ERROR = 2,
- LOG_FATAL = 3.

The default is 0

Hope this helps you!

Comment: @TomTom see edit... just add the `options` to the driver

Comment: Yes, I make how you write, but I have yet all network
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities        
        caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
        caps['loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'warning'}
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps)
        self.driver.get('http://10.0.0.3:8541/login')
        for entry in self.driver.get_log('performance'):
            print(entry['message'])

Comment: I know a problem is with:
for entry in self.driver.get_log('performance'):
            print(entry['message'])

Comment: I should change performance to performance WARNING, but I dont know how

Answer (score 1):

See the updated answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20910684/10525667.

Starting from chromedriver, 75.0.3770.8, you have to use goog:loggingPrefs instead of loggingPrefs:

```
d['goog:loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }
```

Comment: Strangest thing.. I have been using `loggingPrefs` without issue until now.  This was using the latest drivers too.  I can't explain why it worked without `goog:` for the past couple years.