# Get info and warnings consol logs from Chrome with Selenium from specific commands

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, console.log

I am trying to get logs from Chrome's console using Selenium with Python and a little bit lost because it is my first experience with it.

In general, the code works and prints logs, *but I need to see some specific events, that I normally see by typing a command `_newsb.getEv.getBuffer()`* (it is an imaginary command, I am using something similar). With Selenium, I am trying to input it like this `driver.execute_script("_newsb.getEv.getBuffer()")`, but I don't see events.

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

dc = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
dc['goog:loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=dc, service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=D:\\qc1.log"])
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

driver.get('https://www.somewebsite.com/')
page = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("html")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 400)") 
time.sleep(3)
driver.execute_script("_newsb.getEv.getBuffer()") 
time.sleep(3)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY + 400)") 
time.sleep(3)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY + 400)") 
time.sleep(1)

for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
    print(entry)
driver.quit()
```

Could someone please point out what I am doing wrong and how do you input in console with Selenium and Python? Any advice is appreciated.

Also, how to see all logs, including info and Verbose, not just errors?

Answer (score 5):

```
options.set_capability("goog:loggingPrefs", {  # old: loggingPrefs
    "browser": "ALL"})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    options=options
)

# returns a list of all events


driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
driver.execute_script("console.error('This is error')")
driver.execute_script("console.info('This is info')")
driver.execute_script("console.log('This is log')")

logs = driver.get_log("browser")

print(logs)
sleep(100000)
```

This prints all the 3 types of logs i am not sure if you are looking for this

Comment: Thanks, @PDHide. You are correct, it is getting all 3 types of logs. But I still have one problem: I do not see the output of _newsb.getEv.getBuffer(). 

Is this `driver.execute_script("_bewsb.log.getBuffer()") ` correct way to send it? Or is there a special method to get the response?

Comment: what is that function ?its a function in your website or a general one ?

Comment: This is not a general one. We use it to see specific events related to our product only (it is not exactly like the one I used in the example). The events are not seeing unless I type something like that in the Chrome console. It will return an object with all the events I need to track.

Comment: so in the console it does prints all information ? then try adding a time.sleep(5) before get_log

Comment: to avoid opening another question, does anyone knows how to to the same in JS?