# Capture console.log outputs on Chrome console using selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, console.log

I have a list of websites which I am doing some testing and experimentation on. I visit a website from the list using selenium and inject a piece of JS into some of the files using MITMproxy scripting. This injected code performs some test and output the results using console.log() in JS onto the chrome console, something like

> `console.log(results of the injected JS)`

The injection is successful and the results which I desire do appear on the Chrome Console when I run my experiment. The issue that I am facing is when I try to capture the chrome console for console.log output, it is not successful. It will capture warning and error message from chrome console but not `console.log` output. Currently this how I am doing it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException, StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

option = Options()
option.add_argument('start-maximized')

# Specify the proxy
option.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s:%s' % (proxy_host, proxy_port))

# enable browser logging
d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
# d['loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }
d['goog:loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }


# Launch Chrome.
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option, executable_path = './chromedriver', desired_capabilities=d, service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=./js_inject/qc1.log"])

for url in list_urls:
# Navigate to the test page

    driver.get(url)
    sleep(15)
    # in this 15 seconds, the MITMproxy will inject the code and the injected code will output on chrome console.
    for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
        print(entry)
```

Can anyone point me what mistake I might be making or an alternate approach to perform this task. Thank you.

P.S Pardon me for grammatical errors.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response. No, I still have not found a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
dc = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
dc["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {"browser":"INFO"}
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, desired_capabilities=dc)
```

I managed to make it work a while ago, so not sure what exactly did it, but I think it was the experimental option of "anable-logging".

Comment: Just a heads up: this answer did not work for me, and this one did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66466176/598057.