# Get console logs in Chrome with Selenium 4 and Javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium for a super simple test, using chrome; I am trying to get in the chrome tools some `console.log`s for debugging, but for some reasons logs are not available at all. I also tried `console.warn` and `console.error` to check if it was a matter of debug levels, but still nothing.

I used an argument to open chrome tools at start: `options.addArguments('--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs')` (you can see it below);

Here's my code:

```
import { Builder, By, Key } from 'selenium-webdriver'
import { assert, expect, should as loadShould } from 'chai'
import { it } from 'mocha'

import chrome from 'selenium-webdriver/chrome.js'

// patch to make should chainable
const should = loadShould()

let driver = {}

describe('a second test block', async () => {

  before(async () => {

    let options = new chrome.Options()
    options.addArguments('--window-size=1980,1024')
    options.addArguments('--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs')
    
    options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.All)    // <--- here I'm trying to enable logging

    var capabilities = {
      'browserstack.timezone': 'Rome',
      // ... other capabilities
    }

    driver = await new Builder()
      .withCapabilities(capabilities)
      .forBrowser('chrome')
      .setChromeOptions(options)
      .build()
  })

  it('another test', async () => {

    // trying to log, but nothing shows up
    console.log('start')
    
    // navigate to app
    await driver.get('https://lambdatest.github.io/sample-todo-app/')

    // add a todo
    await driver.findElement(By.id('sampletodotext')).sendKeys('learn selenium', Key.RETURN)

    // assert
    let todoText = await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//li[last()]')).getText()

    assert.strictEqual(todoText, 'learn selenium')

    expect(todoText).that.is.not.a('number')

    todoText.should.equal('learn selenium')

    // close the browser
    // await driver.quit()    // <--- commented out to check chrome tools console
  })
})
```

This code throws an error about the arguments in `options.SetLoggingPreference`; if I remove this line, instead of printing in chrome tools console `start`, it shows nothing.

I read about this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66465158/get-info-and-warnings-consol-logs-from-chrome-with-selenium-from-specific-comman) in which the answer is made using Python, but I need to do it in Javascript.

I also tried reading all the [chrome capabilities](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities) and the [chrome command line arguments](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) (which can be added with `options.addArguments()`, but nothing worked.

any clue on how to do it?

Comment: Have you read this ?
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/logging ? Try adding theses arguments : `--webview-verbose-logging` and `--log-file`

Comment: sadly does not work, I also tried creating a new test using google page, to be sure that some website settings are blocking logs

Comment: well I am using VS code and I discovered that logs are currently printed on the TERMINAL. No idea why