# Scraping Browser Console Output - Python Selenium - TCF API

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, asynchronous

I want to scrape so-called TC-strings (Tracking Consent Strings) from sites that implement the so-called [Tracking Consent Framework](https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/GDPR-Transparency-and-Consent-Framework) for GDPR compliance.

In the browser console I can enter something like

```
window.__tcfapi('ping',2,function(data,success){console.log(data);})
```

The description of the API can be found here [TCF API](https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/GDPR-Transparency-and-Consent-Framework/blob/master/TCFv2/IAB%20Tech%20Lab%20-%20CMP%20API%20v2.md#ping). The third argument is the callback function to write the received data to the console.
The desired return value (he example is from [focus.de](https://www.focus.de/)) would be a dictionary that looks like this

```
{
"cmpId": 6,
"cmpVersion": 1,
"gdprApplies": true,
"tcfPolicyVersion": 2,
"cmpLoaded": true,
"cmpStatus": "loaded",
"displayStatus": "hidden",
"apiVersion": "2",
"gvlVersion": 82}
```

How would I be able to assign this console output to a variable in python using Selenium?

I could try executing the script with the `execute_script`-method like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
cap = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
cap["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {"performance": "ALL"} 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=cap)
driver.execute_script("window.__tcfapi('ping',2,function(data,success){console.log(data);})")
```

And then getting the console logs, like it is discussed in this question: [Getting console.log output from Chrome with Selenium Python API bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907180/getting-console-log-output-from-chrome-with-selenium-python-api-bindings)

However this seems very inefficient and I surmise my problem stems more from a misunderstanding of asynchronous javascript programming.

I also tried using the `execute_async_script` method.
But that only results in a timeout error for me.

Any hints are greatly appreciated, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it (temporarily) using this workaround:

```
tcs = driver.execute_script("window.__tcfapi('ping',2,function(data,success){window.tcs=data;}); return window.tcs")
```

So basically I changed the callback function to set a global variable `window.tcs` which then can be accessed and returned within the function that is executed when we use Selenium's `execute_script` method.

I am aware that setting global variables is a bad idea...

However you can also remove it with `driver.execute_script("delete window.tcs")`.