# Python Selenium Get Console Output

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

As you can see the console in chrome driver outputs "Maiya Health Frusso 1.0",
How do I get that text and print it in python's console?

Comment: Have you gone through the selenium Docs ?

Comment: Try looking at this StackOverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907180/getting-console-log-output-from-chrome-with-selenium-python-api-bindings

Answer (score 0):

1st find the element using:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name(<< CLASS NAME >>)
```

or

```
element = find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, << CLASS NAME >>)
```

Then:

```
print(element.text)
```