# How to get log console messages with Selenium on Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I used a code with Selenium on Python that types JavaScript code on Chrome console. That JS code returns me a list as the image show:
[console response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRd8O.png)
I want to get the two People lists to python so I can work with them, How con I do that?

I tried other answers like:

```
logs =  driver.get_log('browser')
for log in logs:
    print(log)
```

But this get me a lot of errors, also I tried to get the logs of a different website just to learn how to get them, but this code doesn't get all the logs, just few of them.

Also I tried using `DesiredCapabilities` and verbose, enable logging but doesn't seems to work.

```
d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
d['loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=d, options=options, service_args=["--verbose", "--enable-logging --v=1"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a hint in [resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20910684/20443541)

Looks like `d['loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }` specification isn't supported with your chromedriver version (since `75.0.3770.8`)

Try using the following:

```py
d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
d['goog:loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=d, options=options, service_args=["--verbose", "--enable-logging --v=1"])
```

Comment: Also tried that in the morning, but just keep not working

Comment: What chromedriver and Chrome version are you running on?